# JavaScript isn't getting all cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to get stored cookies using JavaScript.  Here's a list of cookies shown in Google Chrome by inspecting the page and going to Resources.

[image]

When I run the code:

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

It only shows the K----S------C---- cookie, but not the adminhtml cookie.  How do I access the adminhtml cookie?

===================================================

Edit:

According to the selected answer,  JavaScript can't access HTTP-only cookies.  Though I found a workaround. It might not be the most secure, but in a scenario like this where you need to get the cookie information, try this.

Use PHP to write the cookie information to a hidden div:

```
<div id="adminhtml" style="visibility:hidden"><?php
    echo $_COOKIE['adminhtml'];
?></div>
```

Then use JavaScript to get the innerhtml of the div:

```
<script>
    var cookieValue = document.getElementById("shopperid").innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508027/cant-access-cookies-from-document-cookie-in-js-but-browser-shows-cookies-exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adminhtml appears to be a HttpOnly cookie. You can't access HttpOnly cookies from javascript.

Quote from wikipedia, can't find the official docs:

> The HttpOnly attribute is supported by most
>   modern browsers. On a supported browser, an HttpOnly session
>   cookie will be used only when transmitting HTTP (or HTTPS) requests,
>   thus restricting access from other, non-HTTP APIs (such as
>   JavaScript). This restriction mitigates but does not eliminate the
>   threat of session cookie theft via cross-site scripting (XSS).
>   This feature applies only to session-management cookies, and not other
>   browser cookies.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I don't know if it's the most secure way to do things, but I found a workaround. I'll post it as an edit for anyone that might want it.