# cookie created on server side can't be read on client side

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a problem reading a cookie with javascript on client side. I know how to create a cookie and to read it from the client side, but I can't read a cookie on client side, which was created by the server with NodeJS. However, I can see this cookie with Firefox's developper tools, but console.log(document.cookie) dosent get me this cookie.

Any lead ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add the code examples of how are you creating/obtaining the cookie? You can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17508321/2111274).

Answer (score 0):

Okey, the problem I had is that my cookie had the property HttpOnly set to true, so I couldn't access it from Javascript on my client side. I just set it to false and it worked.