# Create the session using java without using servlet

Tags: java, session

I have java application which has token based authentication ,
I am not using servlets ,once user is logged in i need to maintain the session for some time . i am not able to figure out how to achieve this.

```
if(response_code == 200){
//logged in and set session here
}
else{
//unauthorized
}
```

the above shows the skeleton and session needs to be set there, so even if user comes without token next time he should be able to log in.
How to achieve this in java

Comment: What is the restriction of using servlets? It will be like reinventing the wheel if you have to implement sessions.

Comment: No i am modifying elasticsearch source which is in java. so i cannot use servlet.

Comment: if not  session how to create cookie and send it as response in java

Comment: You cannot create a cookie as well since its in javax.sevlet package. I guess you have to create your own Class which has the logic of tracking time verifies if the user is in a session.

Comment: i created cookie in elasticsearch using HtpCookie. how do i set it in response header.

Comment: I think you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17508321/4597596 to do that.

Comment: check my answer i tried