# Setting "document.cookie" prior to launching it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a site on chrome but I need to change a cookie (SERVERID) to a particular id. Using html and JavaScript seems to be the most viable option from what I can tell.

I wanted to set the set the cookie then try launch the website in the same document. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 
                   document.cookie = "SERVERID=VENSWEB6;path=/";        
            document.location.replace('www.urlofwebsite.com');         
        </script>       
    </head>
</html>
```

I tried to set the cookie after replacing it; nothing changes.

I tried the line : `document.cookie = "SERVERID=VENSWEB6;path=/";` on the console of the developer tool on chrome and it worked. It changed the SERVERID cookie value. So the actual code works, it's the execution that I'm struggling at.

[screenshot of the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3U1n.png)

Thanks in advance

Sulav

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access cookies from document.cookie in JS, but browser shows cookies exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508027/cant-access-cookies-from-document-cookie-in-js-but-browser-shows-cookies-exist)

Comment: Are you trying to set a cookie for a domain other than the one you've loaded your page from? That won't work: [Setting cookies to foreign domains will be silently ignored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: When I state the domain I want to set Cookie in, it doesn't make difference.