# Cookies not accessible in react, but shown chrome developer tools. Django RF backend

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, cookies, token

I am having trouble getting tokens from cookies in frontend, although I can see the cookies set in chrome developer tools with `httpOnly` set to `False`. I am doing local development with:

- React frontend (http://localhost:3000/)
- Django backend (http://127.0.0.1:8000/)
- Chrome for web browser, chrome developer for debugging.

In Django rest framework, I have

```py
# views.py
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name="dispatch")
class SetCsrfTokenAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        response = Response({"success": "CSRF cookie set"})
        response.set_cookie(
            "my_cookie", "cookie_value", max_age=3600, secure=True, samesite="None"
        )

        return response

# settings.py

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True


CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
# CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ["Content-Type", "X-CSRFToken"]

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    # "*",
]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
...
]
```

Using react frontend, i make a fetch request with to the endpoint that hits `SetCsrfTokenAPIView`.

```js
const data = await fetch(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/csrf/`,
          {
            method: "GET", 
            credentials: "include", // This is equivalent to Axios's `withCredentials: true`
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json", 
            },
          }
        );
```

Call is successful and I can see the token values in chrome developer tools
[token in Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFCbh.png)
[header in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwuzi.png)

However, when i use `js-cookie`, `react-cookie` or `document.cookie` to get the cookie contents, it cannot find any cookie set from django. If i write a cookie entry by hand on chrome developer, then react can find the handwritten cookies only. The keys and values (value of `Secure`, `httpOnly`, etc) are the same as the ones set from django

How can I access cookies in react frontend? My goal is to extract the value and submit the value using the `X-CSRFToken` header.

### What I did so far

I have scavenged relevant django forums and stackoverflow here. Lots of posts comment on making `HttpOnly` to `False` in the backend cookie setting and in the frontend setting  `credentials: "include",` in the requests. I also tried both fetch and axios.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940908) on the duplicate. Specifically the second bullet point. You've set the cookie to be secure and are using HTTP (not HTTPS). That obviously won't work.