# Javascript - Delete Cookie by the beginning of the name

Tags: javascript, cookies

I do several tax document registrations on a Brazilian government website, and recently the site is rejecting the registrations after making a certain amount in sequence. I looked here in Chrome and saw that when the site rejects it creates a cookie with the name that begins with "TS" and if I delete it the site will accept the registrations again normally.

I would like to know how to delete this cookie through javascript, because the name always starts with TS, but after of the letters have random numbers.

Comment: And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515222/how-to-find-cookies-which-begin-with-string-word-and-extract-information-from).

Comment: I got able to delete with the Javascript code of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form